# Failed to create Azure storage account via Postman

Tags: postman, azure-storage-account, azure-rbac

I am trying to create storage account via Postman. I created one service principal via Azure Portal and got access token with below parameters:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id='client_id'
&client_secret='client_secret'
&grant_type=client_credentials
&resource=https://management.azure.com
```

I tried to create storage account using generated access token with below query:

```
PUT
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subscriptionid/resourceGroups/resourcegroupname/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storageaccountname?api-version=2018-02-01
```

But I got the error like below:

```
{
"error": {
"code": "AuthorizationFailed",
"message": "The client 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' with object id 'XXX does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/read' over scope '/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/resource/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/account' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."
}
}
```

I am the Global Admin and have owner access at subscription level.
Could anyone suggest me what else needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To resolve the error, try assigning **`Storage Account Contributor`** role to service principal at subscription level like below:**

[image]

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error when it dint have the required permissions like below:***

[image]

**After granting the permissions, I was able to create the storage account successfully like below:**

[image]

**To confirm the above, I verified it in the Portal like below:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[How to create Azure Storage Account with REST API using Postman – A Turning Point (raaviblog.com)](https://raaviblog.com/how-to-create-azure-storage-account-with-rest-api-using-postman/)

Comment: Thanks, it worked after assigning that role! Still don't know why it is needed even though I have owner access:)